# how to get path of internal downloads folder in flutter

Tags: flutter, path, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages

I want to get Path of the internal download folder `/storage/emulated/0/Download`.

what I have tried :

[This plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider). but it throws an error and in repo also suggested that :

> This plugin has lots of inconsistencies and should no longer be used. Feel free to fork and tweak it.

help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

In my case.:

`getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();`

Returns the flutter directory path. With the folder: "app_flutter" at the end. You might change this path to find the download directory.

Comment: I have already tried this and also mentioned in question what I need.

Comment: In my case I just replaced the "app_flutter" Folder with the Documents folder. Maybe this works for you as well